# Material Autocomplete Angular Stopping Api Call when Selected From the Autocomplete Dropdown options

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using Material Angular Autocomplete Dropdown feature to fill place predictions in my dropdown. I am using onChange of material to call the api from the Service I have created. My issue is that when I select predictions from the select box, an api call gets fired to the node server, because the onChange is fired again. So, I want to stop the Api Call to the service when an option is selected from the dropdown.
Here's the code of the template!!

```
    <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput type="text" name="location" placeholder="Search By Location" aria-label="Location" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="location">
       <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="location">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let places of predictions" (optionSelected)="predictionSelected($event)" [value]="places.description">
           <span>{{places.description}}</span>
         </mat-option>
       </mat-autocomplete>
   <mat-form-field>
```

And in my component.ts I have written a function that would call my google maps services and would fetch my prediction onChange. I have created an event function which is (optionSelected) which fires when value from the dropdown is selected.

```
predictionFilled = false;
ngOnInit() {
    this.customForm.get('location').valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value) => this.onChangeLocation(value)
    );
  }

  onChangeLocation(location) {
    if ( this.predictionFilled ) {
      return;
    }
    this.googleMapsService.suggestPlaces(location);
    this.placesPredictions = this.googleMapsService.getPredictionsUpdateListener().subscribe((predictions: Places[]) => {
      console.log(predictions);
      this.predictions = predictions;
    });
  }

  predictionSelected(event: any) {
    this.predictionFilled = true;
  }
```

The issue is that when I click the options from the dropDown the event (optionSelected) is fired after the valueChanges event. Technically, the event optionSelected should fire before the onChange but I don't understand why the event valueChanges is fired before the optionSelected event.

Comment: Guys, you can suggest me some other ways of implementing this too!!

Comment: Why don't you call `predictionSelected()` from `form valueChanges` event? So that you don't need to register `(optionSelected)` event as well.

Comment: How would I do that? Can you help me with some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing with the `event` inside `predictionSelection()`.

You can simply write that single line within formControl `valueChanges` event and remove `(optionSelected)="predictionSelected($event)"` from the `mat element` where it is registered. Also no need of `predictionSelected(event : any)` method.

To stop calling api call, you can check if the value entered exists in the `predictions` array and then make the decision.

```
this.customForm.get('location').valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value) => {
           if (this.predictions.findIndex(value) > -1) {
                  this.predictionFilled = true; // value exists, then do not make api call
           }
           else {
                this.predictionFilled = false; // make api call
           }
           this.onChangeLocation(value);
      }
 );
```

Comment: Won’t work this way! As this won’t send any Api calls then, setting true on changing the location input value would set the predictionfilled true, also i think i can’t set prediction filled true with that syntax. What I want is, that when user types in input field the API would get suggestions and then when user would select something from dropdown the api call should be avoided!! If this is not the proper way, you can suggest me some other way of implementing this feature.

Comment: Thanks for identifying that wrong syntax and check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a simple problem, I just had to compare the prediction array values with the selected value and toggle the boolean.

Comment: Yes, it happens. Sometimes we try to overlook simple problems and make them complicated :)